# Ajax Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am not able to figure out the cause of the error. I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null` error. I do have `.product-btn` class defined in the button.

Here is the Complete Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.product-btn').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('data-action')=="add"){
          ajaxSubmit('/add/product/'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'/');
              $(this).attr('data-action','remove');
              $(this).children('span').html('Remove from cart');
      }else{
        ajaxSubmit('/remove/product/'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'/');
            $(this).attr('data-action','add');
            $(this).children('span').html('Request Price');
      }
    });
</script>
```

And the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse btn-embossed product-btn" data-action="add" data-id="<?php echo $productId; ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery? What's the output of `console.log($.fn.jquery)`?

Comment: Yes,l I have included jQuery. I am getting  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined` with `console.log($.fn.jquery)`

Comment: Then `$.fn` shouldn't be `undefined` Check the include again

Comment: Jquery should be included before your script (better to include in head section), and also include your script before closing body tag.

Comment: @Andreas I am still getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined` Can this be due to `prototype.js` because I also have it included?. @viktor-kukurba Yes, the `jQuery` is first in the header.

Comment: Yes, that should be the problem. They also use `$` ( http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/)  Do you need both of them?

Comment: @Andreas yes, I need both of them. I tried putting jQuery in no conflict mode and now I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxSubmit is not defined`

Comment: Where is `ajaxSubmit()` coming from? It's not part of jQuery itself. You could write your own `ajaxSubmit` or use `$.ajax({url: /add/product/` + $(this).data("id") + "/"})` directly

Comment: @Andreas Your suggestion worked. How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: As I haven't written an answer you cannot accept it^^ Just write yourself an answer and accept it. But stay with the "cannot read ..." problem caused by the inclusion of jQuery and prototype. The effect on `ajaxSubmit` is just a follow up of this.

Answer (score 0):

Give the function inside ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.product-btn').click(function(){
                if($(this).attr('data-action')=="add"){
                  ajaxSubmit('/add/product/'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'/');
                  $(this).attr('data-action','remove');
                  $(this).children('span').html('Remove from cart');
                }else{
                    ajaxSubmit('/remove/product/'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'/');
                        $(this).attr('data-action','add');
                        $(this).children('span').html('Request Price');
                  }
                });
        });
```

Comment: jQuery won't return `null` if a selector didn't match any node in the DOM.

Comment: No, but it won't crash with an `cannot read ... of null` error